# UISearchController unexpected paint of UITableView in status bar since IOS 13

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

I have a very basic UITableController within a very basic UINavigationBar using a very basic UISearchController ( but `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES` ).
The issue I have is that if the search is active the UITableView scroll is visible in the statusbar. Note that this behavior is new since IOS13 , before due to the opaque search bar this didn't happen. It looks more like an IOS bug to me than the expected behavior.
Any suggestions how to fix this ? Ideally I'd like to have the same appearance like in IOS12 and before.

IOS 13, scrolling visible in statusbar[image: IOS 13, scrolling visible in statusbar]

IOS 12, search bar half way opaque: no problem
[image: IOS 12, search bar opaque: no problem]
<sub>(source: [generomobile.de](https://www.generomobile.de/gmi/so_IOS12ok.jpg))</sub>

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchResultsUpdating>
{
  UIWindow* _win;
  UINavigationController* _nav;
  UITableViewController* _tc;
  NSMutableArray* _model;
  NSArray* _filteredModel;
  UISearchController* _search;
  UILabel* _label;
}
@end
@implementation MyAppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  _win=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  UIViewController* c=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
  UIView* v=c.view;
  v.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor;
  _label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 20)];
  _model=[NSMutableArray array];
  _label.text=@"Tap on 'Show Table'";
  [v addSubview:_label];
  for (int i=0;i<200;i++) {
    _model[i]=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d",i];
  }
  _nav=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:c];
  c.navigationItem.title=@"A title";
  UIBarButtonItem* b=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show Table" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showTable:)];
  c.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=b;
  _tc=[[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
  _tc.definesPresentationContext=YES; //have to do it for other reasons
  _search=[[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
  _search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation=NO; //needed to be able to tap in results
  _search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation=YES; //have to do it for other reasons
  _search.searchResultsUpdater=self;
  UITableView* tv=_tc.tableView;
  tv.delegate=self;
  tv.dataSource=self;
  tv.tableHeaderView=_search.searchBar;
  _win.rootViewController=_nav;
  [_win makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
-(void)showTable:(UIBarButtonItem*)b {
  [_nav pushViewController:_tc animated:YES];
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  _label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You selected row:%ld",(long)indexPath.row];
  [_nav popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return _search.active?_filteredModel.count:_model.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString* reuse=@"whatever";
  UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuse];
  if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:reuse];
  }
  NSInteger row=indexPath.row;
  cell.textLabel.text=_search.active?_filteredModel[row]:_model[row];
  return cell;
}
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
  NSString* searchText=searchController.searchBar.text;
  if (searchText.length==0) {
    _filteredModel=_model;
  } else {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                              @"SELF contains[c] %@",searchText];
    _filteredModel=[_model filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
  }
  [_tc.tableView reloadData];
}
@end
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
      return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue and can't find any decent solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this (mis)behavior is that on IOS13 the `UISearchBarBackground` view does not cover the status bar anymore. It did cover it in previous IOS versions.

IOS12 `UISearchBarBackground` covering the whole upper area[image: covers the whole upper area]

IOS13 `UISearchBarBackground` not covering the statusbar[image: covers only the status bar itself]
<sub>(source: [generomobile.de](https://www.generomobile.de/gmi/so_IOS13Background.jpg))</sub>

The solution I came up with without touching any other ViewController hierarchies in my code was a pretty nasty hack, extending the frame of the `UISearchBarBackground` to match with the state in pre IOS13 versions.

```
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
  NSString* searchText=searchController.searchBar.text;
  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    if (searchController.active) {
      //The intrinsic UISearchBar code seems to adjust the
      //background view of UISearchBar later on thats why we
      //need to delay
      [self performSelector:@selector(adjustBg) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
  }
  if (searchText.length==0) {
    _filteredModel=_model;
  } else {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                              @"SELF contains[c] %@",searchText];
    _filteredModel=[_model filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
  }
  [_tc.tableView reloadData];
}
CGPoint pointInScreen(UIView* v,CGPoint pt)
{
  CGPoint ptWin=[v.superview convertPoint:pt toView:nil];
  CGPoint ptScreen=[v.window convertPoint:ptWin toWindow:nil];
  return ptScreen;
}
-(void)adjustBg
{
  //ugly: we try to adjust the background view of the UISearchBar
  //to the top of the screen (like it was in pre IOS13 times)
  if (!_search.active) {
    return;
  }
  UISearchBar* bar=_search.searchBar;
  if (bar.subviews.count==0) { return; }
  UIView* first=bar.subviews[0];
  if (first.class!=UIView.class || first.subviews.count==0) { return;}
  UIView* bg=first.subviews[0];
  if ([bg isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
    CGSize size=bg.frame.size;
    CGPoint orig=bg.frame.origin;
    CGPoint p=pointInScreen(bg,orig);
    CGPoint p2=pointInScreen(bg, CGPointMake(0, orig.y+size.height));
    if (p.y>0) { //not top of screen
      bg.frame=CGRectMake(orig.x,-p.y,size.width,p2.y);
    }
  }
}
```

It's really not the solution I was looking for , but as long there is no better one, I need to maintain that (and post it here in case someone else stumbles across that)